# What does mouse position argument signify in mouse.move command?

Tags: g1ant

In this particular code if for mouse.move command I am giving argument 1100/500 it is moving toward right and if I am giving argument as 100/500 it is moving towards left doesn't matter where the target position is. Even for 500/500, it is moving toward the right, what does it mean?

```
keyboard ⋘WIN+D⋙
mouse.click 336⫽49 relative false type down
mouse.move 1100⫽500 wait 1000 relative false
mouse.click 1819⫽870 relative false type up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example `mouse.move` won't make a big difference to the whole automation because you have ordered a robot to press the left mouse button at the `336⫽49` position and then move somewhere randomly (to the `1100⫽500` position) and finally move to the `1819⫽870` position and unpress the left mouse button.